# On conflict delete postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, sql-delete

I am trying to toggle a relation in a single query where it deletes the relation if it already exists, otherwise it creates it. I could add a third column with a bool that toggles it but I would rather delete it.

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thread_subscription (
    profile_id     INTEGER REFERENCES profile (id),
    thread_id      INTEGER REFERENCES thread (id),
    UNIQUE(profile_id,thread_id)
)
```

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO thread_subscription (profile_id,thread_id) 
VALUES ($1,$2) ON CONFLICT (profile_id,thead_id) 
DO DELETE FROM thread_subscription 
WHERE profile_id = $1 AND thread_id = $2;
```

Comment: What do you want to do when the `profile_id,thread_id` that you are trying to insert already exists in the table ? Not `DELETE` it I imagine ?

Comment: Yes I want to delete it (just the relation not the actual profile or thread). This query is behind an api endpoint the toggles the subscription status of a user's profile to a forum thread.

Comment: So you run an `INSERT` against a table, and you expect that in some cases it would actually perform a `DELETE` ? That does not look like a good way to proceed. If you want to `INSERT`, then `INSERT`. If you want to `DELETE`, then `DELETE`. But that choice has to be made in the application, before running the query

Comment: I want to toggle a relation in a single query. I don't think that is an obscure operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your intent is to run an `INSERT` order on a table, and you expect that on duplicate keys it will actually `DELETE` the related record. While technically feasible, I would not recommend this set up, because this is *action at a distance*, which is hard to debug.

The same type of functionnality however could be achieved with a Postgres function. This makes the intent explicit when it comes to *toggling* the subscription, and does not interfere with standard database statements (`INSERT`).

Here is the code for the function : it takes two parameters as input, verifies if a record is already there in the subscriptions table, and then performs the relevant operation ; it returns `0` on `DELETE` and `1` on `INSERT`. You can see [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3c3ebeee1961c3486155f2c9da8f3ec3) for a full demo of how it works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toggle_subscription(
    pid NUMERIC, 
    tid NUMERIC
) 
RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
DECLARE
    row_exists NUMERIC;
BEGIN

    SELECT 1 
    INTO row_exists 
    FROM thread_subscription 
    WHERE profile_id = pid and thread_id = tid;

    IF (row_exists > 0) THEN
        DELETE FROM thread_subscription WHERE profile_id = pid and thread_id = tid;
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO thread_subscription(profile_id, thread_id) VALUES(pid, tid);
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;

END; 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the GMB's response, you can avoid using variable with using **PERFORM** instead of using  **SELECT**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toggle_subscription(
    pid NUMERIC, 
    tid NUMERIC
) 
RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$

BEGIN

    perform FROM thread_subscription WHERE profile_id = pid and thread_id = tid;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO thread_subscription(profile_id, thread_id) VALUES(pid, tid);
        RETURN 1;

    ELSE
         DELETE FROM thread_subscription WHERE profile_id = pid and thread_id = tid;
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END;     
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[this is](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=47a3e8c1266c5b43fc0ae3e76db51ce4) fiddle link.